# Any examples of using of access database values using JQuery UI slider and Asp.net mvc?

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to pull data from a SQL server table with the JQuery uI slider [widget](http://jqueryui.com/slider/) and Asp.net mvc 5.  I am trying to find examples on the web.  Anyone know of any good resources?

```
@model XXXX.Evaluator.Data.EntityModel.EvaluationQuestion

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<div class="container">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuestionsText)

        <div class="panel-body">
            @if (@Model.ResponseType.Description == "Number")
            {
                <p>
                    <label for="amount">Selected Value:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="hidden" style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
                </p>

                <div id="slider-@(Model.ID)"></div>
            }
            @*else if (@Model.ResponseType.Description == "Text")
            {
                /* Insert text box for the user to type in their response. */
                <input type="text" multiple />
            }
            else if (@Model.ResponseType.Description == "Percentage")
            {
                /* Insert slider or text box for user to indicate percentage. */
            }*@


        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#slider-@(Model.ID)").slider({
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 10,
            step: 1,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#selected-value-@(Model.ID)").val(ui.value);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am getting instance of an object not found.

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the exception?

Comment: @Html.LabelFor(model => model.QuestionsText)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I wasn't calling the correct model and session variables from the previous page.